# Not able to select an element using xpath

Tags: xpath, cucumber

Tried my level best, but I am not able to write a XPath that returns a unique element in this situation.

**xpath 1:** return all 7 elements under Default value, as all the elements have input tag

//div/span[contains(text(),'Default Values')]/ancestor::div/span[contains(text(),'Select Date')]/following-sibling::div//input

**Xpath 2** returns 3 elements, the drop-down in the image.

//div[@class='_selectContainer_psmgei']/div//input

Screenshot:
[Window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqM7W.png)

HTML Screenshot: [HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1bUc.png)

Comment: What are you trying to get? A single xpath for each of the 7 elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get one unique input element, you need something like this :

For the first XPath :

```
//span[contains(text(),'Select Date')]/following::div[@class="Select-input"][1]/input
```

Replace [1] with [2] or [3] to access the input element you want.
I've replaced "following-sibling" from your expression since the span element has no div sibling.

For the second XPath :

```
(//div[@class='_selectContainer_psmgei'])[1]//input
```

Replace [1] with [2] or [3] to access the input element you want.